# Does it follow from abc conjecture that $\Omega(p^{2}-1)>max(\Omega((p-1)^2-1),\Omega((p+1)^2-1) $?

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, abc-conjecture

It seems that when  $ n $ is prime, the map  $ f $ that maps an integer  $ n $ to the number  $ \Omega(n^2-1) $  of primes dividing the argument counted with multiplicity is larger than the same function evaluated in  $ n-1 $ and in  $ n+1 $ .
Is it true? Does it follow from abc conjecture?

Comment: For prime $p=1688123$, we have $f(p-1)=f(p+1)=7>6=f(p)$.

Comment: Thank you very much. Are there finitely many such counterexamples ?

Comment: There are $160059$ counterexamples for $p<10^8$, and $161$ of them are strong counterexamples such that $f(p)<\min\{f(p-1),f(p+1)\}$. So I guess there are infinitely many, but it is hard to prove.